# Table export to excel using alasql in Chrome 32bit version getting TypeError: get_URL(...).createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, google-chrome

Am trying to export table data into excel sheet using alasql.js.It's working fine in Mozilla firefox and Googlechrome 64bit version but am getting error in Google Chrome 32bit version.
I tried FileSaver.js also same error am facing. 
Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

> Here is a my code.

```
Data : [{"id":"1","firstname":"test","lastname":"test2","email":"test@gmail.com","phone_number":"7204690129"}]
```

> In Controller.js

```
var exportDataexel = $scope.data;
```

`$scope.exportDataExcel = function () {
         alasql("SELECT firstname AS Firstname,lastname AS Lastname,email AS Email, phone_number AS Phonenumber INTO XLSX('Report.xlsx',{headers:true}) FROM ?",[exportDataexel]);
};`

In console displaying error like this.

```
angular.min.js:107 TypeError: get_URL(...).createObjectURL is not a function
at new FileSaver (alasql.js:17501)
at saveAs (alasql.js:17577)
at saveWorkbook (alasql.js:15284)
at doExport (alasql.js:15169)
at Object.alasql.into.XLSX (alasql.js:15142)
at eval [as intoallfn] (eval at <anonymous> (alasql.js:7259), <anonymous>:3:33)
at queryfn3 (alasql.js:6548)
at queryfn2 (alasql.js:6295)
at Object.eval [as datafn] (eval at <anonymous> (alasql.js:7633), <anonymous>:3:57)
at alasql.js:6246
```